# Why Laravel AuthGuard interface doesn't have the attempt() method?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

In Laravel docs it is stated to use the attempt() method to authenticate, however it is not in the Auth Guard interface, and so your custom guard fails.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `SessionGuard` has this method as it implements the `StatefulGuard` interface. The other guards do not have this method, so it can't be part of the `Guard` interface as not all guards are stateful.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand what method is being called by default in my guard for automatic login (aka silent login). Say I have a JWT guard, I authenticated and sent a token. Now I make a request with that token. What method will Laravel call in my custom Auth Guard?

Comment: depends what is happening and what you are doing, often the `user` method is hit to resolve the user from the guard which usually does the work

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Auth` facade to authenticate users.

```php
using Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// $credentials should have 'email' and 'password' keys
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    // success
}
```